# Jooq complains about Java Runtime class version in Spring Boot despite Java 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11, jooq

I have a SpringBoot project with Java 11(!), SpringBoot 2.6.7, JOOQ 3.16.6 and Postgres 42.3.3.
When I run spring context in tests I get this:

```
ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jooq/DSLContext has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

How should I understand it? The Java version I use in my build is 11 which is the same version that JOOQ uses in its dependencies. Why then the compiler complains about version mismatch? 61.0 denotes Java 17 which is never used in my project.

Comment: Can you add the pom xml / gradle build file?

Comment: You're probably using a commercial JDK 17 distribution of jOOQ? The build file would help figure this out...

Answer (score 3):

The jOOQ Open Source Edition increased the baseline JDK version to Java 17
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12430.

Thus your JOOQ is getting compiled by Java 17 while you have specified the java version for your application as 11. To solve this error you will probably have to upgrade java version from 11 to 17.

But if you are licenced you can still use java 11 and JOOQ by downloading the right distribution [here](https://www.jooq.org/download/versions)

Comment: OP was using jOOQ 3.16, though, at least that's what they claimed. The Java 17 baseline was implemented only in jOOQ 3.17

Comment: Yes, but when you are using the open source edition it only supports the latest version. You can check that out on their website (For open source, Language support is Java 17 or newer). The jOOQ Open Source Edition supports the latest version from the commercial editions. Commercial editions support a variety of SQL dialect versions backwards compatibly.

Comment: I know "their" website very well, for I made it ;-) What you're saying is true for the jOOQ 3.17 Open Source Edition, which requires Java 17 (and it may well be that OP is accidentally using that). But if they are indeed using jOOQ 3.16 as they claim, then perhaps, they just downloaded the wrong commercial distribution, namely the one that also requires Java 17...

Comment: Thank you, it seemed that It was caused by IntelliJ's stale caching of dependencies